# send message to user using UCWA API

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest, ucwa

I would try UCWA API by sending a post request to a client. Here's the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/startmessaging_ref)

After app initialization I create my request.

```
const request = require('request-promise');
...

let URL= "https://************.lync.com"
let req= {
    url: URL + body.communication.startMessaging,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "authorization": "Bearer " + APP.Token
    },
    body: {
        importance:"Normal",
        sessionContext:"33dc0ef6-0570-4467-bb7e-49fcbea8e944",
        subject:"Sample Subject Line",
        telemetryId:null,
        to:"sip:hamza@opencircle.co",
        operationId:"5028e824-2268-4b14-9e59-1abad65ff393"
    },
    json:true
}
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
    console.log(req);
    request(req).then(res=> {console.log("OK",res)},err=> console.log("ERRoR",err.message)).catch(err=>console.log("ERROR CATCH",err));
})
```

I get this error message

> '400 - {"code":"BadRequest","subcode":"CallbackUriUnreachable","message":"Exception of type \'PlatformService.Web.ValidationException\' was thrown.","debugInfo":{"errorReportId":"a8034d8ad14c4b0695f7f78dc12c19fe"}}'

Comment: Are you using a specific library for `request`? At first glance, it looks that you are not embedding values like `operationId` inside the body of the POST request

Comment: I'm using request-promise library

Comment: Ok, can you try setting the parameters for [Request body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/startmessaging_ref#request-body) under a property named `formData`? Something like [here](https://github.com/request/request/tree/master/examples#flickr-image-upload).

Comment: I have changed it to body not form data as mentioned it in request-promise package on github but still have this error `400 - {"code":"BadRequest","subcode":"CallbackUriUnreachable","message":"Exception of type 'PlatformService.Web.ValidationException' was thrown.","debugInfo":{"errorReportId":"0ea13fc537ab4faabcdc9faad2e28746"}}
`

Comment: Did you added the `json: true` option? Also, does `body.communication.startMessaging` contains a valid path?

Comment: Yes I have added `json:true` and url should be OK, I doubt that the operationId is not working because I have hard typed a random string ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177235/discussion-between-infodev-and-rodrigo-mata).